# Hide / Remove 'End Chat' button Live Agent chat window

Tags: jquery, liveagent

It's possible to hide or remove the 'end chat' button from the live agent chat window?. I tried to use Jquery across an iframe but looks there're no way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The only way it would be by creating your own chat window, of course, not a practical option.